# Spring boot: @Profile @Bean combination doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've coded these two beans:

```
@Bean
public HttpClient httpClient() throws Exception {
    LOG.debug("http client for NO PRE");

    return HttpClients.custom().build();
}

@Bean
@Profile("pre")
public HttpClient httpClientPre() throws Exception {
    LOG.debug("http client for PRE");

    //...

    HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().build();

    return client;
}
```

By other side, I've this another bean:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder, HttpClient httpClient) throws Exception {
    return builder.requestFactory(() -> new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient))
            .build();
}
```

As you can figure out, when `"pre"` is active I want `httpClientPre` is reached. However, in spite of active profile is "pre", it's not reached. See logs:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.4.RELEASE)

13:20:31.746 [main] INFO  n.g.t.e.s.SchedulerApplication - Starting SchedulerApplication on psgd with PID 9538 (/home/jeusdi/projects/repositori-digital/rep-digital-scheduler/target/classes started by jeusdi in /home/jeusdi/projects/repositori-digital)
13:20:31.760 [main] DEBUG n.g.t.e.s.SchedulerApplication - Running with Spring Boot v2.0.4.RELEASE, Spring v5.0.8.RELEASE
13:20:31.767 [main] INFO  n.g.t.e.s.SchedulerApplication - The following profiles are active: pre  <<<<<<<<<<<<
```

However, I was expecting to get log for `"http client for PRE"`. Nevertheless, I'm getting:

```
13:20:48.613 [main] DEBUG n.g.t.e.s.c.ServicesConfiguration - http client for NO PRE <<<<<<
```

It means that `httpClientPre` is not reached in spite of current profile is `pre`.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I've also tried with `@Profile("!pre")`, but I'm getting this message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of method restTemplate in net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.scheduler.config.ServicesConfiguration required a bean named 'httpClient' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'httpClient' in your configuration.
```

**EDIT2**

I've also tried with:

[image]

But it keep getting message above.

Comment: What if you add `Profile("!pre")` to the first bean?

Comment: how do you enable profile `pre`?

Comment: @Kayaman I've edited post.
@AdamSiemion setting `spring.profiles.active` property on a `properties` file.

Comment: @AdamSiemion You can see that current active profile is `pre` on posted log when service starts.

Comment: What if you change the name of the parameter in `restTemplate` to `HttpClient httpClientPre`?

Comment: `@Profile` means the code will be executed only when the profile condition is met. If you do not have @Profile, then it will be executed in any case. hence both the beans are getting initialized. Assume you have  global variables and function variables. global variables are initialized even if the function is not called. function variables are initialized(along with global variables) when function is called.

Comment: NONONONO, paste code not screenshots.

Comment: But the funny thing in your case is that `!pre` works while `pre` does not :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason here is that you are creating beans with 2 different names (method name == name of bean) and name of bean is taken into account when injection happens - there bean name == argument name.

In your case you are injecting `httpClient` but you are creating `httpClient` and `httpClientPre` - thus `httpClient` is injected

using `@Profile("!pre")` is the way to go but in conjunction with `@Qualifier` so you can name the bean correctly, eg.

```
@Bean
@Profile("!pre")
public HttpClient httpClient() throws Exception 

@Bean
@Profile("pre")
@Qualifier("httpClient")
public HttpClient httpClientPre() throws Exception
```

Comment: Also I've yout approach and it seems the behavior is keeping on. I mean, I'm getting `Parameter 1 of method restTemplate in net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.scheduler.config.ServicesConfiguration required a bean named 'httpClient' that could not be found.`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should mark **all** `@Bean` methods with `@Profile`

According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html

> NOTE: With @Profile on @Bean methods, a special scenario may apply: In the case of overloaded @Bean methods of the same Java method name (analogous to constructor overloading), an @Profile condition needs to be consistently declared on all overloaded methods. If the conditions are inconsistent, only the condition on the first declaration among the overloaded methods will matter. @Profile can therefore not be used to select an overloaded method with a particular argument signature over another; resolution between all factory methods for the same bean follows Spring's constructor resolution algorithm at creation time. Use distinct Java method names pointing to the same bean name if you'd like to define alternative beans with different profile conditions; see ProfileDatabaseConfig in @Configuration's javadoc.

Comment: He does have distinct method names, so this case does not apply.